# View multiple images & videos - flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a list which contains multiple url strings like

```
var list = [
    "https://.../1.jpg",
    "https://.../2.png",
    "https://.../3.mp4",
    "https://.../4.avi",
 ];
```

My problem now is i want to be able to view and play this url as images and videos but don't know what plugin to use. I tried this way

```
int curIndex = 0;
...
Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: theme.primaryVariant,
            ),
            child: widget.url[curIndex].split(".").last == 'mp4'
                ? VideoPlayer(data: widget.url[curIndex])
                : phView()),
        onLongPress: () {
          bottomSheet(
              context,
              imgBS({
                "name": widget.url[curIndex].split("/").last,
                "url": widget.url[curIndex],
              }, context));
        },
        onVerticalDragEnd: (data) {
          if (data.primaryVelocity > 200 || data.primaryVelocity < -200) {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

```
Widget phView() {
    return PhotoViewGallery.builder(
      scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      onPageChanged: (idx) {
        setState(() {
          curIndex = idx;
        });
      },
      builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
          imageProvider: (widget.type == null ||
                  widget.type == 'network' ||
                  widget.type == '')
              ? NetworkImage(widget.url[index])
              : FileImage(widget.url[index]),
          initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
          errorBuilder: (context, object, trace) =>
              Center(child: Icon(Icons.info)),
          minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
          maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered * 1.5,
        );
      },
      itemCount: widget.url.length,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      loadingBuilder: (context, event) => Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 20.0,
          height: 20.0,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            value: event == null
                ? 0
                : event.cumulativeBytesLoaded / event.expectedTotalBytes,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black87,
      ),
    );
  }
```

and for the video player i used the [flick_video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flick_video_player) package but this isn't what i want so please is there a way to view all this and be able to swipe through each other like fb